# not able to exit from the container as exit cmd hungs

Tags: docker

```
docker exec -it --user testuser dbcont bash 
<run some cmd>
<type exit>
```

Process hangs and not coming out of the container. Even when we press Ctrl+c, the process is not exiting.

How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

In another terminal you could find the process with `ps -aux | grep docker` then kill it with `kill -USR1 <<PID>>` or if that doesn't kill it then `kill -9 <<PID>>`

Depending on your system, the flags in the ps may be different - double check the man page.

Comment: Though you should probably try to find out why the process is not responding to ctrl+c

Comment: As a temporary work around, yes i used to do the same method like grep for the docker pid and kill it manually. But when it comes to automation, we are finding difficulties on handling this issue. 

So we need the solution from the docker experts to let me know if any other settings has to be applied on the kernel or docker registry files to overcome this issue?  Appreciate your help on this regards!

Comment: What does your Dockerfile for dbcont look like?